# WPF application crash after ClickOnce publish

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I have a problem with ClickOnce publishing of a WPF application.

- If the application is built (debug or release), it is running correctly.
- Application published by ClickOnce crashes.

I tried to change Target Platform. Sometimes this change helps to solve problems, but not every time (1 of 20 cases).

I have Visual Studio 2008 and the project has been upgraded from Visual Studio 2005.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No ideas on the cause of the crash but I would make my exception logging more robust and see if that catches the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I have exception logging and no my code is runned. I assume the problem is in some .NET loader code. Few months ago I have found that this problem is related to upgrade of V2k5 project to V2k8 version. My assumption is that XAML resources are not built correctly.

Comment: After many attempts to debug crashing code I see now IOException: Cannot locate resource 'controls/MyControl.xaml'.

Comment: it is really missing in built code. Very interesting is that in that 1 case when application is published correctly there are all resources! So xaml (baml) resources are not compiled correctly!

Comment: How are your resources declared within the project? Depending on whether or not your resources are declared app-level or lower could make a big difference when you're building, especially when determining how your views are referencing them.

Answer (score 2):

On the machine where the application is installed, drill down in the user profile to the ClickOnce cache, and look for the cached application files. The folder will have the exe and all of the assemblies, etc., in it. Our winform app creates two folders, xxxx_tion is the one the application runs from.

Find the exe file and double-click on it to run it. This essentially runs the application without the ClickOnce-ness of it all. If it crashes, then it is not a ClickOnce problem per se, it is a problem with your application.

I would check and make sure you are deploying all of the files you need, you don't have references to multiple versions of the same dll, you don't have circular references, etc.

Good luck,
RobinDotNet

Answer (score 1):

There is a long discussion on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3e6909ef-2ab1-4b77-8bc2-796c065a6219/

Solution that worked for me (send by pindurav on page above):

- I rebuild whole solution
- close visual studio
- open visual studio, open project and **directly publish without building**.

= no app.xaml exception