# ClickOnce, my app crashes Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce, visual-studio-express

I'm finishing up a C# app for work, and looking to make a ClickOnce installer.

Right now, I just want to make sure the installer works and that I am able to run the exe without Visual Studio.

So I set up my project to require Windows Installer and .NET 3.5 SP1, and tell it to download from a vendor (I'll be including the components later, but not for this test). It's just a basic utility that won't need updates, so I disable updates and tell it to use a CD/DVD install method since I just want to run it locally. When I run the resultant setup.exe, I get the installation prompt, and MyApp appears in Add/Remove Programs. But, as soon as the installer finishes it crashes with this message:

> [MyApp] has encountered a problem and
>   needs to close.  We are sorry for the
>   inconvenience.

The same message pops up when you try to run the .exe. No Start Menu folders are created during installation. I tried doing away with creating the setup file altogether so it just generated the .application file, but I still got the same error.

Am I missing something obvious? My app compiles in Release configuration and runs just fine. Is ClickOnce just not supposed to work with regular WinForms applications?

This question:
[WPF application crash after ClickOnce publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420280/wpf-application-crash-after-clickonce-publish)
Sounds similar to my issue, but I'm using Windows Forms, and thus not getting an XAML exception. It just refuses to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start is to add a handler for the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.  This is the event which is raised when an exception occurs inside your code and is not handled by a `try/catch` block (or is re-thrown and never handled again).  .NET's behavior in this condition is to close the application--from it's perspective there is a runaway error.

In this event handler, you should--at a minimum--log the error in a manner that ensures it will be written before the application closes.  This could be a very rudementary MessageBox to show the error contents, writing to a text-file, or (preferably) writting to a common logging location.

Comment: >_<
You're right! Thanks for helping out a newbie. Turns out one of my schemas wasn't set to build as Content, so XmlReader was going nuts.